# Perl array element manipulation

Tags: arrays, perl

I've been trying and trying with this one, but it just doesn't seem to click.
If I have an array with let's say 6 numbers:

```
@a = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

1. How do I get every second index ( 2, 4, 6) in this case?
2. how do I compute the difference of every two elements, so
   the output here would be:

> 1 1 1 (because 2-1 =1 and 4-3 =1 and so on..)

Comment: Perhaps you would get a more valuable answer if you posted your attempts. Then we could tell you why your attempts failed. As well as present a working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: don't ever use `$a` or `$b`, they're special  (`sort` uses them) ... it's generally better to give your variables a descriptive name, name it as to what's in there rather than what type of variable it is.

```
for ( my $index = 0; $index < scalar( @pairs ); $index += 2 ) {
  my $first = $pairs[ $index + 0 ];
  my $second = $pairs[ $index + 1 ];
  my $pair = $index / 2;
  my $difference = $second - $first;
  print "the difference of pair $pair is $difference\n";
}
```

Comment: If `@pairs` isn't used after the loop, a destructive `while` loop is much clearer: `while (@pairs) { my $x = shift(@pairs); my $y = shift(@pairs); my $diff = $y - $x; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $index = 1;
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6);
for (@a) {
    if ($index % 2 == 0) {
        my $diff = $_ - $a[$index-2];
        print $diff;
    }
$index++;
}
```

Comment: You should not use `map` as a `for`-loop. You should use `for` for that. Also, you should use proper variable names and make use of spaces and indentation, this is not code golf.

Comment: I fixed your question for you. Notable in this rendition is that you do not need the `$diff` variable, you can just print the subtraction. Also, that it would be much easier to just loop over the indexes.

Comment: I appreciate that, but you left a bug in `my $diff = $_ - $a[$c-2];` which i have fixed :)

Comment: Wouldn't want you to think I would do *all* the work for you.. :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you should post your earlier attempts. In my opinion, the best way to learn is to learn from your mistakes, not being presented a correct solution.

For this problem, I think I would use a C-style for-loop for the first part, simply because it is straightforward, and can easily be tweaked if some new requirement comes up.

The second problem can easily be solved using a regular Perl-style for-loop.

```
use strict;
use warnings;   # always use these two pragmas

my @nums = 1..6; 
my @idx;
for (my $n = 0; $n <= $#nums; $n += 2) {    # loop from 0 to max index, step 2
    push @idx, $n;                          # store number in @idx
}
print "Indexes: @idx\n"; 

my @diff;
for my $n (0 .. $#nums - 1) {               # loop from 0 to max index minus 1
    push @diff, $nums[$n + 1] - $nums[$n];  # store diff in @diff
}
print "Diff: @diff\n";
```

**Output:**

```
Indexes: 0 2 4
Diff: 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use the new `List::Util` pair functions.

For your first question:

```
use List::Util 'pairvalues';

my @seconds = pairvalues @list;  # yields (2, 4, 6)
```

For your second question:

```
use List::Util 'pairmap';

my @diffs = pairmap { $b-$a } @list;  # yields (1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`:

```
my @a = 1 .. 6;
print join ' ', 'Every second:', map $a[ 1 + $_ * 2 ], 0 .. $#a / 2;
print "\n";
print join ' ', 'Differences:', map $a[ 1 + $_ * 2 ] - $a[ $_ * 2 ], 0 .. $#a / 2;
print "\n";
```

Comment: While I do agree `map` is awesome, it's not necessarily what I'd suggest to a beginner.

Comment: @Leeft `map` isn't really that special, its a loop that returns a list at the end, that is all.

Comment: Thank you, will try to grasp the idea of map.

Comment: @user3523464: It just takes a list, runs the given code/expression on each member, and returns a list of the results.

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't use variables `a` and `b`. `$a` and `$b` are special variables used in sorting. Just be a bit more descriptive of your variables (even if it's merely `@my_array`) and you should be fine.

You can loop through your array any which way you like. However, I prefer to use a `while` loop instead of the thee part `for` because the three part `for` loop is a bit misleading. It is a `while` loop in disguise and the promised indexing of the loop can be misleading.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my @array = qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 );
my $index = 1;      # Remember Perl indexes start at zero!
while ( $index <= $#array ) {
    say "Item is $array[$index]";
    say "The difference is " . ($array[$index] - $array[$index-1]);
    $index += 2;
}
```

You said every *second* element. Indexes of arrays start at 0, so you want the odd number elements. Most of the answers use [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) which is a very nice little command, but does an awful lot in a single line which can make it confusing for a beginner. Plus, I don't think the Perldoc on it is very clear. There should be more simple examples.

The `say` is a newer version of `print`. However `say` always adds a `\n` at the end. You should always `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These will catch about 90% of your programming bugs.

The `qw( ... )` is a quick way to make an array. Each *word* becomes an array element. You don't need quotes or commas.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ar = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

# 1. How do I get every second index ( 2, 4, 6) in this case?
my @even = map { $_ & 1 ? $ar[$_] : () } 0 .. $#ar;

# 2. how do I compute the difference of every two elements?
my (@c, @diff) = @ar;
push @diff, -1 * (shift(@c) - shift(@c)) while @c;

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@even;
print Dumper \@diff;

1;

__END__
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          4,
          6
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          1,
          1
        ];
```